# Complex integration confusion

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

I wish to compute $\int_{C}(x^2 - iy^2)dz$, where $C := \{z\mid |z|=1\}$  is positively oriented.

I am a bit confused on what $dz$ actually is.

I know I have $\int_{C}x^2dz - i\int_C y^2dz$, but I still need to know what $dz$ is so I can differentiate in terms of $x,y$. Or maybe I put $x,y$ in terms of $z$.

$z = x+iy$, so then $dz = (x+iy)dx,\; (z+iy)dy$?

---

So the definition of complex integration is:$$\int_{C}f(z)dz = \int_{C}(u+iv)(dx+idy)$$
$$ = \int_{C}(udx - vdy) + i\int_{C}(vdx + udy)$$ where $f(z)=x+iy$.

So how do we deal with the contour?

Comment: Actually, $dz = dx + i\, dy$.

Comment: The way I learned it $\mathrm dz$ has no meaning. You want to find $\displaystyle \int _C\left(\Re(z)\right)^2-\left(\Im(z)\right)^2\mathrm dz$. Use the definition and do it.

Comment: @GitGud I've updated my confusion

Comment: Try $z=e^{i\theta}$, where $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @Creme_brulee OK, sorry. I can't help you. I'm not familiar with this. The definition I know is $\displaystyle \int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\int \limits_a^bf(\gamma(z))\gamma'(z)\,\mathrm dz$, where $[a,b]$ is the domain of $\gamma$.

Comment: @GitGud Sorry. The definition I found was from: http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/jav/soton/HELM/workbooks/workbook_26/26_4_basic_cmplx_int.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parametrize $C$ by setting $z = e^{it}$, $0 \le t \le 2\pi$. Then $x = \cos t$, $y = \sin t$, and $$dz = dx + i\, dy = (-\sin t - i\cos t)\, dt.$$ Thus

\begin{align}\int_C (x^2 - iy^2)\, dz &= \int_0^{2\pi} (\cos^2 t - i\sin^2 t)(-\sin t - i\cos t)\, dt\\
& = \int_0^{2\pi} [-(\cos^2 t\sin t+\sin^2t \cos t) + i(\sin^3 t - \cos^3 t)]\, dt,\\
\end{align}

which I leave to you to compute.

Comment: Was my definition for the complex integral not correct? From what I understand, you are using the definition GitGud said.

Comment: I said in the beginning before your edit that $dz = dx + i\, dy$. The definition you have written in your edit is exactly the one I used (in my case, I used directly the $\int_C (u + iv)(dx + i\, dy)$ definition).

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks!